# Using distutils where swig interface file is in src folder

Tags: python, swig, distutils

I've got a setup.py that looks something like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
import glob

sources = glob.glob('src/*.cpp') + glob.glob('src/*.i')
# this is ugly, but otherwise I get the wrapper included twice
sources = [source for source in sources if '_wrap' not in source]
setup(
    name = 'engine',
    ext_modules = [
        Extension(
            '_engine',
            sources = sources,
            swig_opts = ['-c++'],
            include_dirs = ['src']
        )
    ],
    py_modules = ['engine']
    package_dir = {'' : 'src'}
)
```

Now this works as long as I run `install` twice. The first time, swig creates the engine.py in the src directory. But it doesn't get copied to the target. The second time I run the setup.py file, the engine.py gets found and is installed. Is there a way to make it all work the first time?

Comment: I have a simpler setup even than yours but I found I have to do the same. One "workaround" was to run build first, then install, but all that does is generate the swig wrapper so that install sees it. It gets copied in the install phase instead of build.

Answer (score 2):

I do agree that this should work out of the box, and would consider it a bug.

One option to get this working is to simply change the order in which things are build. By default, `setup.py` will first collect the python modules, then build any external packages.

You can change the build order by sub-classing the default `build` class, and then ask `setup.py` to use your custom `build` class via the `cmdclass` option.

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from distutils.command.build import build as _build

#Define custom build order, so that the python interface module
#created by SWIG is staged in build_py.
class build(_build):
    # different order: build_ext *before* build_py
    sub_commands = [('build_ext',     _build.has_ext_modules),
                    ('build_py',      _build.has_pure_modules),
                    ('build_clib',    _build.has_c_libraries),
                    ('build_scripts', _build.has_scripts),
                   ]

 setup(
    name = 'engine',
    cmdclass = {'build': build },  #Use your own build class
    ext_modules = [Extension('_engine',
                             sources = sources,
                             swig_opts = ['-c++'],
                             include_dirs = ['src']
                   )],
    ...
```