# setup.py: run build_ext before anything else

Tags: python, swig, setuptools, distutils, setup.py

I'm working with a setup.py that creates a whole bunch of SWIG interface files during the build_ext step. This needs to run first, because subsequent build steps need a full list of the python files to work properly (like copying the python files to the package directory, creating the egg, creating the sources list, etc.).

This is what currently happens when you do `setup.py install`:

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
```

The `build_py` step tries to copy all the python files that it finds to the build directory. Those files don't exist until `build_ext` runs (swig creates a bunch of .py files).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666018/using-distutils-where-swig-interface-file-is-in-src-folder/26556654#26556654) recommends changing `sub_commands` but that didn't appear to do anything.

I tried just subclassing the `install` command class like this to run `build_ext` before anything else:

```
class Build_ext_first(setuptools.command.install.install):
    def run(self):
        self.run_command("build_ext")
        super(Build_ext_first, self).run()
```

..and then working it in to setup with `cmdclass`:

```
setup(
    ...
    cmdclass = {'install' : Build_ext_first}
)
```

But that didn't work because `super` doesn't work with old-style classes and `install` apparently doesn't inherit from `object`.

How do I do `build_ext` first?

Comment: You may want to rephrase your OP, as it's not clear what your problem is.

Comment: How's that? I just added the list of steps and what specifically goes wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears the old way of doing super() is forwards-compatible so I just did that:

```
class Build_ext_first(setuptools.command.install.install):
    def run(self):
        self.run_command("build_ext")
        return setuptools.command.install.install.run(self)


setup(
    ...,
    cmdclass = {'install' : Build_ext_first}
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me out.

Answer (score 12):

For fear of posting on a 2 year old post. I think the correct way to solve this would be to fix it during the "build" phase:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Extension
from setuptools.command.build_py import build_py as _build_py    

class build_py(_build_py):
    def run(self):
        self.run_command("build_ext")
        return super().run()

setup(...,
    cmdclass = {'build_py' : build_py},
)
```

That way it works for bdist_wheel as well as install (haven't tested other stuff).

Note the `super` syntax is a bit different in Python 2:

```
class build_py(_build_py):
    def run(self):
        self.run_command("build_ext")
        return _build_py.run(self)
```

Comment: This results in:
`File "/tmp/pip-qtEO8z-build/setup.py", line 51, in run
      return super().run()
  TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
`

Comment: super has a different syntax for python 2.7. Above is valid for python 3

Comment: That done the trick for me. I had a similar problem with a pure interface swig module (just an .i -file).