# Building a module with setuptools and swig

Tags: python, python-3.x, swig, setuptools

I have a bunch of SWIG interfaces (foo.i, bar.i, etc.). I want to build them into a Python (3.6.4) module for my platform (MS Windows), with setuptools. The module should include the SWIG-generated Python files (*.py), the binary extensions (*.pyd) and the compiled caches (*.pyc). My setup.py is essentially like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from pathlib import Path
paths=list(Path('.').glob('*.i'))
py=[path.stem for path in paths]
ext=[Extension('_' + path.stem, [str(path)]) for path in paths]
setup(py_modules=py, ext_modules=ext)
```

Now I build it with the following steps:

```
python setup.py build_ext -I..\include --swig-opts="-I..\include -c++" -b pkg
python setup.py build_py -c -d pkg
echo. > pkg\__init__.py
```

Using these steps, I get exactly what I want, under the `pkg` directory.

My question is: Is there no way to get this effect using a single invocation of `setup.py`, e.g., `setup.py build`? I think that build is supposed to call build_ext, but then I cannot see how to pass, e.g., the swig-opts option.

### Update

Passing the SWIG options is solved (h/t @hoefling). The solution looks like this:

```
ext=[Extension(name='_' + path.stem,
            sources=[str(path)],
            swig_opts=['-I../include', '-c++'],
            include_dirs=['../include'])
            for path in paths]
```

*However*, with that layer of the onion peeled off, I can now see the layer below, which is this: `setup.py build` as a single invocation, wants to run the `build_py` first, and then `build_ext` afterward. Can you see why this fails? I have no Python sources. The Python scripts in my module are to be generated by SWIG, but SWIG doesn't get run until the `build_ext` step. Thus, I end up with the same question, which is how to build the module in a single invocation.

```
C:\some\path> python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
file foo.py (for module foo) not found
file foo.py (for module foo) not found
running build_ext
building '_foo' extension
swigging foo.i to foo_wrap.cpp
swig.exe -python -I../include -c++ -o foo_wrap.cpp foo.i
creating build
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I../include /EHsc /Tpfoo_wrap.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\foo_wrap.obj foo_wrap.cpp
Creating build\wib.win-amd64-3.6
link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /EXPORT:PyInit__foo build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\foo_wrap.obj /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_foo.cp36-win_amd64.lib
Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_foo.cp36-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_foo.cp36-win_amd64.exp
Generating code
Finished generating code
```

When complete, foo.py exists in the current working directory next to foo.i, and _foo.cp36-win_amd64.pyd exists under build\lib.win-amd64-3.6. (FYI, this transcript is edited slightly to protect proprietary information, e.g., I don't show all the full paths to all the echos of commands. And I did not include bar.i in the sources.)

To clarify:

1. The error is this one: `File foo.py (for module foo) not found`
2. Though all the required files exist in the output, except foo.cp36-win_amd64.pyc which I could possibly live without, I have to manually copy foo.py and _foo.cp36-win_amd64.pyd into some new directory to make a clean Python module.

Comment: `build_ext` supports SWIG out of the box, so `Extension(name, files, swig_opts=['-I../include', '-c++'])` should build just fine.

Comment: @hoefling This is correct for passing the SWIG options, thanks.

Comment: As for the other error - can you post the complete error message? Just copy and paste the text from the terminal to your question.

Comment: Ah, I see now what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that once you declare `py_modules`, `distutils` includes `build_py` as subcommand in `build` and it is always being executed first because of the ordering of `sub_commands` list in `build` class. It simply doesn't know that SWIG will generate python module wrappers later in `build_ext`. I guess you can see this as a bug since one would expect `distutils` to be able to cope with generated modules, but meh.

Since you only have SWIG interfaces and all of your python modules are generated wrappers (so in your case `build_ext` is not dependent on `build_py`), you can change the ordering of subcommands in `build` so `build_ext` is executed first, then the rest. This will ensure that the python modules are generated before `build_py` is executed.

Basically, you need override the `build` command class and change the ordering of elements in `sub_commands` list. There are lots of ways to reorder a list in python; below is my proposal. For reordering the list I used the list conditional partitioning recipe from [`itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
import itertools
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from distutils.command.build import build as build_orig


def partition(pred, iterable):
    t1, t2 = itertools.tee(iterable)
    return itertools.filterfalse(pred, t1), filter(pred, t2)


class build(build_orig):

    def finalize_options(self):
        super().finalize_options()
        condition = lambda el: el[0] == 'build_ext'
        rest, sub_build_ext = partition(condition, self.sub_commands)
        self.sub_commands[:] = list(sub_build_ext) + list(rest)


setup(
    ...,
    cmdclass={'build': build},
)
```

Comment: Does the job, and explains how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the essential idea (see @hoefling's answer) is to subclass the build command to set its sub_commands property, this works:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from distutils.command.build import build

class build_alt_order(build):
  def __init__(self, *args):
    super().__init__(*args)
    self.sub_commands = [('build_ext', build.has_ext_modules),
                         ('build_py', build.has_pure_modules)]

setup(py_modules=['foo.py', ...],
      ext_modules=[Extension('_foo', swig_opts=...), ...],
      cmdclass={'build':build_alt_order})
```

Comment: Alternatively, here is a slightly simpler version that I've found also to be more versatile, in that it also works with `install`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48942866/893113

Answer (score 0):

There is a demo project [swig-python-demo](https://github.com/yanqd0/swig-python-demo) with SWIG integrated in `setup.py`.
There are 2 extensions in it.
One (example.c) is by C, and the other is by C++ with STL (stl_example.cpp).

The problem that generated py files missing is also solved by `class BuildPy(build_py)`.

```
EXAMPLE_EXT = Extension(
    name='_example',
    sources=[
        'src/example/example.c',
        'src/example/example.i',
    ],
)

STD_EXT = Extension(
    name='_stl_example',
    swig_opts=['-c++'],
    sources=[
        'src/example/stl_example.cpp',
        'src/example/stl_example.i',
    ],
    include_dirs=[
        'src/example',
    ],
    extra_compile_args=[  # The g++ (4.8) in Travis needs this
        '-std=c++11',
    ]
)


# Build extensions before python modules,
# or the generated SWIG python files will be missing.
class BuildPy(build_py):
    def run(self):
        self.run_command('build_ext')
        super(build_py, self).run()


setup(
    name='swig-example-demo',
    description='A Python demo for SWIG',
    ...
    ext_modules=[EXAMPLE_EXT, STD_EXT],
    cmdclass={
        'build_py': BuildPy,
    },
    ...
)
```